# How to create an ArrayList of images and use it in ExpandableListViewAdapter

Tags: android

I'm working on an `ExpandableListView` Activity in Android, in which I want to implement images as group and child icons. I want to set an `ArrayList` of images in the `MainActivity.java` and refer to them in `ExpandableListAdapter.java` as an `ImageResource`. Can somebody help me how to figure it out?

### Update

**Here is the MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

CustomExpandableList listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_list);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new CustomExpandableList(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            switch (groupPosition) {
            case 0: 
                switch (childPosition) {
                case 0: 
                    Intent protheanIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
FWH.class);
                    startActivity(protheanIntent);
                    break;              
                }
            case 1:
                switch (childPosition) {
                case 0: 
                    Intent asariIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FIH.class);
                    startActivity(asariIntent);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
            }
        });

}

/*
 * Preparing the list data
 */
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("First Group");
    listDataHeader.add("Second Group");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> fwh = new ArrayList<String>();
    fwh.add("First Item");
    fwh.add("Second Item");

    List<String> fih = new ArrayList<String>();
    fih.add("First Item");
    fih.add("Second Item");

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), fwh); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), fih);


}
```

**Here is my ExpandableListAdapter:**

```
public class CustomExpandableList extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public CustomExpandableList(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.child_name);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.group_name);

    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Post any relevant code you have written that has tried to solve this.

Comment: check the posted link.

Comment: Edited My Question. Check it out. Thanks

Comment: Did u try suggestion in posted link ?

Comment: I checked it, but I want to set icons for both groups and childs of an `ExpandableListView` like the `ArrayListString` in my code.

Comment: whats the issue in it ? inflate custom layout for both parent & child & on their respective getviews perform suggested working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted an answer for this here:

[Android set image on ListView in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434182/android-set-image-on-listview-in-fragment/25434415#25434415)

You have to make a custom Adapter, on Parent & child getview you can do this for Expandablelistview. Make custom layouts for your parent & child & inflate them.

**Update**

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ....

            drawerItem_LogoParent = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ParentImage);

drawerItem_LogoParent.setImageResource(logosparent[intPosition]);

            return convertView;
        }


    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
            {
                drawerItem_Logo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childImage);
drawerItem_Logo.setImageResource(logos[intPosition]);
    return convertView;
    }
```

You can place your image array inside activity (call it in get view)

```
private int[] logos = {
            R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2, R.drawable.pic3, R.drawable.pic4, R.drawable.pic5 
        };
```

Comment: Where should I put the Icon Array code? I want to put my ArrayList in the Main Activity (not in the Adapter)

Comment: Any where inside your activity,you just have to call it inside getview

Comment: Thanks, but I want to put my ArrayList in MainActivity (See updated question)

Comment: @Ruhollah what em I saying to you ? Inside your MainActivity put your icon array,  & make a custom adapter class inside your MainActivity too & in its getview method call that icon array..

Comment: Of course, sorry guys, I'm new in Android and got a little confused. Let me try your help. Thanks again

Comment: sure try & no limit in asking if u learn somthing out of it, if it solve ur issue accept as answer